# Error occured when trying to connect to SALES_DATA in Petaho Data Integration with the Hypersonic connection type and Native(JDBC) access

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I am implementing the ***Chapter 1: EXTRACT AND LOAD (Retrieve data from a flat file)*** tutorial by Hitachi Vantara. I am supposed to retrieve data from a flat file and loading it to a database. After creating the text file input and adding the hops between the file input and table output, the connection wasn't successful after creating it with the following:

- Connection name: Sample Data
- Connection type: Hypersonic
- Access: Native (JDBC)
- Host name: localhost
- Database name: sampledata
- Port number: 9001
- Username: pentaho_admin
- Password: password

**Error occured while trying to connect to database**

```
Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Any idea about how to solve this?
Is there a specific driver I have to download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to take input from flat file (TXT, EXCEL, CSV) and insert those values to Hypersonic DB.

Look like you want to use Pentaho server default Hypersonic DB. So before use this DB, you should run Pentaho Server to active & use Hypersonic DB.

Can you please confirm your Pentaho Server[ Hypersonic DB ] is running? Because I did not found any issue when I do the same thing from here.

Your driver should have already in your PDI path 'data-integration9.1\lib\hsqldb-2.3.2.jar'

Comment: Is the Pentaho server got installed by default with PDI? If so, How can I run it, because it doesn't seem like there is a directory for the server in PDI?

Comment: No, Pentaho server not installed by default with PDI .You suppose to install Pentaho server if you need. But now my question is where is your Hypersonic DB running. As you were trying to connect with a Hypersonic DB.  Is it really running on your localhost?

Comment: I didn't run the Hypersonic DB before trying to connect to it. Do I have to run the localhost manually and then the Hypersonic Db afterwards in order for the connection to be established? If so, how to do so?

Comment: The problem was solved! All I had to do was to install PENTAHO SERVER BI and run it, then test the hypersonic connection which passed successfully afterwards.